# Error in SQL Server while updating data

Tags: sql-server

```
Create Table #tempTbl
(
 [AssID] [int],
 [dt] [datetime]
)

insert into #tempTbl 
select distinct(AssignmentID), (case when isdate(substring(NoteText,len('Vehicle picked-up was completed on')+1,len(NoteText)))=1 then
        substring(NoteText,len('Vehicle picked-up was completed on')+1,len(NoteText)) else '01/01/1900' end) as dop
from dbo.Assignment_Notes
where
    AssignmentID in(Select AssignmentID from dbo.Assignment_ClaimInfo 
        where InsuranceComp='Access General')
and
    AssignmentID in (Select AssignmentID from dbo.Assignment_BuyerInfo where PickupDate is null)
and
    NoteTypeID=5

update dbo.Assignment_BuyerInfo 
set PickupDate=#tempTbl.dt 
where AssignmentID=#tempTbl.AssID
```

Comment: please write code in formated way ...

Comment: Please post the error message you're getting too.

Comment: Please edit your question and add some information about what the exact problem is. Are you getting an error message, or is the INSERT or UPDATE not working?

Answer (score 2):

change your update statement to the following:

```
update dbo.Assignment_BuyerInfo 
   set PickupDate=#tempTbl.dt 
  from dbo.Assignment_BuyerInfo, #tempTbl
 where AssignmentID=#tempTbl.AssID
```

You have to include your extra table in a from clause just like you would if you were doing a select statement.